# Unable to convert bytes from charset 65535 in to Japanese (5035)

Tags: java, utf-8, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a character set conversion issue:

I am updating Japanese Kanji characters in DB2 in iSeries system with the following conversion method:

```
AS400 sys = new AS400("<host>","username","password");
CharConverter charConv = new CharConverter(5035, sys);
byte[] b = charConv.stringToByteArray(5035, sys, "試験");
AS400Text textConverter = new AS400Text(b.length, 65535,sys);
```

While retrieving, I use the following code to convert & display:

```
CharConverter charConv = new CharConverter(5035, sys);
byte[] bytes = charConv.stringToByteArray(5035, sys, dbRemarks);
String s = new String(bytes);
System.out.println("Remarks after conversion to AS400Text :"+s);
```

But, the system is displaying garbled characters while displaying.  Can anybody help me to decode Japanese characters from binary storage?

Comment: 65535 is the CCSID for 'this is binary data - do not translate'.  Do you really want to create a Java string tagged as binary data?

Comment: I want to just display the contents of the column in a web page, edit it and update back in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot Jon and Buck Calabro !

With your clues, I have succeeded with the following approach:

```
String remarks = new String(resultSet.getBytes("remarks"),"SJIS");
byte[] byteData = remarks.getBytes("SJIS");
CharConverter charConv = new CharConverter(5035, sys);
String convertedStr = charConv.byteArrayToString(5035, sys, byteData);
```

I am able to convert from string.  I am planning to implement the same with JPA, and started coding.

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know anything about `CharConverter` or `AS400Text`, but code like this is almost always a mistake:

```
String s = new String(bytes);
```

That uses the *platform default encoding* to convert the binary data to text.

Usually storage and retrieval should go through opposite processes - so while you've *started* with a string and then converted it to bytes, and converted that to an `AS400Text` object when storing it, I'd expect you to start with an `AS400Text` object, convert that to a byte array, and then convert that to a `String` using `CharConverter` when fetching. The fact that you're calling `stringToByteArray` in both cases suggests there's something amiss.

(It would also help if you'd tell us what `dbRemarks` is, and how you've fetched it.)

I do note that having checked [some documentation for `AS400Text`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/info/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400Text.html), I've seen this:

> Due to recent changes in the behavior of the character conversion routines, this system object is no longer necessary, except when the AS400Text object is to be passed as a parameter on a Toolbox Proxy connection.

There's similar documentation for `CharConverter`. Are you sure you actually need to go through this *at all*? Have you tried just storing the string directly and retrieving it directly, without going through intermediate steps?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Jon Skeet!

Yes.  I have committed a mistake, not encoding the string while declaration.

My issue is to get the data stored in DB2, convert it into Japanese and provide for editing in web page.  I am getting dbRemarks from the result set.  I have missed another thing in my post:

While inserting, I am converting to text like:

```
String text = (String) textConverter.toObject(b);
PreparedStatement prepareStatementUpdate = connection.prepareStatement(updateSql);
prepareStatementUpdate.setString(1, text);
int count = prepareStatementUpdate.executeUpdate();
```

I am able to retrieve and display clearly with this code:

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT remarks FROM empTable WHERE emp_id = ? AND dep_id=? AND join_date='2013-11-15' ";
prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
prepareStatement.setInt(1, 1);
prepareStatement.setString(2, 1);
ResultSet resultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
while ( resultSet.next() ) {
    byte[] bytedata = resultSet.getBytes( "remarks" );
    AS400Text textConverter2 = new AS400Text(bytedata.length, 5035,sys);
    String javaText = (String) textConverter2.toObject(bytedata);
    System.out.println("Remarks after conversion to AS400Text :"+javaText);
}
```

It is working fine with JDBC, but for working with JPA, I need to convert to string for editing in web page or store in table.  So, I have tried this way, but could not succeed:

```
String remarks = resultSet.getString( "remarks" );
byte[] bytedata = remarks.getBytes();
AS400Text textConverter2 = new AS400Text(bytedata.length, 5035,sys);
String javaText = (String) textConverter2.toObject(bytedata);
System.out.println("Remarks after conversion to AS400Text :"+javaText);
```

Comment: What does 'remarks' look like?  Jon is suggesting that you don't need to convert at all.

Comment: Remarks column is of CHAR type, encoded with CCSID 9307.  So, I am updating in binary format as 65535.

Comment: I can't find CCSID(9307) in my reference, but assuming it's a Chinese encoding, why would you tag it as binary data?  Wouldn't you want to convert from 9307 to your intended Japanese encoding (5305)?

Comment: You are right.  It is in Chinese encoding in database.  But, for displaying as Japanese fonts, I need to convert.  Now, I have succeeded with this coding:

Comment: For other people with similar problems, could you post what worked for you as an answer and then 'Accept' it?

Comment: Sure.  I would like to share my experience and help others to overcome their issues.  Already I have posted my answer.